# How can I ssh into Xeon Phi on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh

On Linux I can ssh into a Xeon Phi card:

```
$ ssh mic0
me@mic0's password:
```

On Windows, however, it doesn't work:

```
> micctrl -s
mic0: online
> ssh mic0
ssh: mic0: no address associated with name
```

How can I connect to my Xeon Phi card on Windows?

Comment: mic0 is a linux hostname - what does it resolve as?

Comment: @LexiR how can I find out what it resolves to? `host mic0` doesn't work ("host not found")

Comment: My coworker has been reading [The documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/335818/intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-quick-start-developers-guide.pdf) and tells me it should be at 172.31.1.1 according to page 12. Is it? (He can't comment due to rep)

Comment: @LexR your link is now dead.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev A quick google for "intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-quick-start-developers-guide.pdf" turned up https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/ee/4e/intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-quick-start-developers-guide.pdf, which looks like the same document.